# Android app won't load on device (Samsung Galaxy S3 phone) or Eclipse's AVD emulator

Tags: android

Trying to load sample My First App (hello world) app from within Eclipse Juno.  Eclipse shows my device is online.  Phone is running Kit Kat 4.4.2.  Developer mode is turned on.  USB debugging is enabled.

Here is the Console output:

```
   [2014-07-02 03:32:15 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
    [2014-07-02 03:32:15 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
    [2014-07-02 03:32:15 - MyFirstApp] No Launcher activity found!
    [2014-07-02 03:32:15 - MyFirstApp] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
    [2014-07-02 03:32:15 - MyFirstApp] Performing sync
    [2014-07-02 03:32:15 - MyFirstApp] Uploading MyFirstApp.apk onto device 'bc176a2b'
    [2014-07-02 03:32:16 - MyFirstApp] Installing MyFirstApp.apk...
    [2014-07-02 03:32:21 - MyFirstApp] Success!
    [2014-07-02 03:32:21 - MyFirstApp] \MyFirstApp\bin\MyFirstApp.apk installed on device
    [2014-07-02 03:32:21 - MyFirstApp] Done!

Absolutely nothing from the hello world app shows up on the phone.  It just continues to display the home screen.

When I try to use Eclipse's AVD to run the app, I get the following Console output:
    [2014-07-02 03:34:48 - MyFirstApp] ------------------------------
    [2014-07-02 03:34:48 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
    [2014-07-02 03:34:48 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
    [2014-07-02 03:34:48 - MyFirstApp] No Launcher activity found!
    [2014-07-02 03:34:48 - MyFirstApp] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
    [2014-07-02 03:34:48 - MyFirstApp] Performing sync
    [2014-07-02 03:34:49 - MyFirstApp] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
    [2014-07-02 03:34:49 - MyFirstApp] \MyFirstApp\bin\MyFirstApp.apk installed on device
    [2014-07-02 03:34:49 - MyFirstApp] Done!
```

While the emulator dialog box (screen) did load, the app did not.  So the emulator dialog box stayed at its home screen.

Please advise.

Here is AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: edit your android manifest , and add intent filter in activity

Comment: Provide Your AndroidMAnifest.xml source please

Answer (score 3):

Use this in android manifest

```
<activity
            android:name="youractivityname"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```